# How to cut off the last entire of dir path with patterns

Tags: bash

DIR=/usr/local/games/**

How to cut them to /usr/local/games in bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for `dirname`?

Comment: ya .i need only /usr/local/games and i want remove /** part

Comment: `$ dirname /usr/local/games/**` outputs `/usr/local/games`